I’ve “proven” a false claim about series but can’t spot the error
Consider the following claim: if $\sum(x_n)$ converges and $(y_n)$ is bounded, then $\sum(x_n)(y_n)$ converges.
In general, this is not true. For example, $\sum(-1)^{n+1}(\frac{1}{n})$ converges and $(-1)^{n+1}$ is bounded, but $\sum(-1)^{n+1}(\frac{1}{n})(-1)^{n+1}$ = $\sum(\frac{1}{n})$ which diverges. Yet apparently I have managed to come up with a “proof” of this claim in general. Of course it cannot be correct, but I am having trouble spotting where the logic in the proof goes awry, so that’s what I would like help with.
Here is my “proof:”
Suppose $\sum(x_k)$ converges and let $(y_k)$ be a bounded sequence. Then we have some $M > 0$ st $|y_k| < M$ for all $k.$ Let $\epsilon > 0$ and let $x,y$ be any real numbers st $x > y.$ This choice of $x$ and $y$ will help us bound sums of $|x_j|. $ By the Cauchy criterion, there is some $N$ st $n > m \geq N$ implies $|x_{m+1} + … + x_n| < \frac{\epsilon}{(x - y)M}.$ Note that, letting $n = m + 1$ this implies $|xj| < \frac{\epsilon}{(x - y)M}$ for all $j \geq m + 1.$ Now, consider the series $\sum(x_n)(y_n)$. For any $n > m \geq N,$ letting $x = n$ and $y = m$
we have $|x_{m+1}y_{m+1} + … + x_ny_n| \leq$$
|x_{m+1}y_{m+1}| + … + |x_ny_n| \leq $$M(|x_{m+1}| + … + |x_n|) <$
$ M(\frac{\epsilon}{(n-m)M} + … + \frac{\epsilon}{(n-m)M}) = \epsilon.$
Therefore by the Cauchy criterion, this proves that $\sum(x_n)(y_n)$ converges.

You proved that $j\geqslant m+1\implies|x_j|<\frac\varepsilon{(x-y)M}$. But after that you cannot decide that $x=n$ and that $y=m$, since $x$ and $y$ are two fixed real numbers such that $x>y$.
